# Go Router: How to implement nested navigation inside a widget

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-go-router, auto-route, flutter-beamer

I want to add nested navigation inside a widget same as this gif: [demo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/slovnicki/beamer/master/examples/multiple_beamers/example-multiple-beamers.gif). I know this feature is available in packages like **[beamer](https://pub.dev/packages/beamer)** and **[auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route)** but I want to know if this is possible with go_router as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using two [`Router.withConfig`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Router/Router.withConfig.html) widgets from Flutter and passing two separate `GoRouter`s to them, like so:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Body(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  const Body({super.key});

  @override
  State<Body> createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  final router1 = GoRouter(
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (context, state) => const Page(),
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: 'sub-page',
            builder: (context, state) => const Page(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
  final router2 = GoRouter(
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (context, state) => const Page(),
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: 'sub-page',
            builder: (context, state) => const Page(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Router.withConfig(config: router1),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: Router.withConfig(config: router2),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final route = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.name;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: InkWell(
        onTap: () => context.go('/sub-page'),
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Route: $route'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to achieve the same with ShellRoute as well?